李白's poem 《越女词·其三》
Here's my attempt to translate this poem by 李白 :

《越女词·其三》
耶溪采莲女,
见客棹歌回。
笑入荷花去,
佯羞不出来。



Songs to Yue women - Part 3
A Yue woman is gathering lotus in the Ye river;
she crosses a passer-by and suddenly turns her boat back, singing.
With a smile, she hides away among the lilies,
seeming too shy to show up.

Is the second line correct? Who is oaring? Who is singing?
Thanks also for eventually correcting mistakes!

Here is the modern Chinese translation of the poem, you can check it against yours.
若耶溪中采莲的少女，见到行客，(她)唱着歌把船划回。
嘻笑着藏入荷花丛，假装怕羞不出来。
https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B6%8A%E5%A5%B3%E8%AF%8D%E4%BA%94%E9%A6%96/3177997

So, definitely, SHE oars and SHE sings, right? My translation seems ok...

Yes, and yes, it is quite accurate. But I would eliminate "suddenly" in line 2, and change "seeming" to "pretending/faking" in the last.

《越女词其三》
李白
耶溪采莲女。
Upon 若耶 creek picking lotus a maiden,
见客棹歌回。
seeing a traveller, she wends her boat.
笑入荷花去。
Laughing she hides midst the lotus clusters,
佯羞不出来。
feigning shyness she remains there.
肯定是个大帅哥！
